# What is the term for out of key playing with a singular monophonic instrument?

Tags: theory, composition, chord-theory, violin, orchestration

Lets say im playing a violin piece that's primarily in C major/G mixo-Lydian but i start to use notes outside of the scale without any chord accompaniment , technically those notes wouldn't be referred to as non chord tones, which include passing tones, incomplete neighboring tones,and etc. So what is the term for using out of scale notes on a monophonic instrument, and if possible can you add some more insight on the topic..Thanks!

Comment: _without any chord accompaniment...non chord tones_ Seems you're asking because there are no chords being played. That really doesn't make much difference: the prevalent tonality - the key - of the melody you're playing implies certain chords and scales, even if they're not being played by an accompanist, so _non-chord tones_ would still be apropos. Perhaps the question is what's the technical term for _non-chord tones_ , which isn't really a technical term. On that, @Tim has given you the answer: Notes within  the  key are generally called _diatonic_, outside the key,  _chromatic_.

Answer (score 1):

Chromatic notes would fit, as in they are not going to be diatonic, thus they're out of the normal scale/mode, and will generally be represented on the dots as accidentals.

Comment: Does using the chromatic notes change the key? and if so how can it re- established on a singular monophonic instrument?

Comment: If the same chromatic notes get used frequently, it could be said that there's a change of key - or just a modulation. Re-establishing key is the same as in any piece - the key notes, particularly root and leading note - are stated more often.

Comment: Can any note aside from the root and leading, be used for re-establishment? And what are the benefits of using the root and leading?

Comment: Leading note usually leads to the root, and then using 3rd and 5th of key will re-tune listeners' ears.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how the notes are being used. Technically they *could* be non-chord tones. You can specify chromatic with NCT's like **chromatic appoggiatura** or **chromatic passing chord**. Also, the chromatic tones *could* result in a shift in key. If it's temporary you could call it a **tonicization**, or if it is longer it could be called a **modulation**. Another term that could be appropriate is **secondary dominant**. It depends on the musical context. Even if the part is monophonic, if chords are being arpeggiated, then using some chord terms would be fine.